# Lookup UK administrative county for point

Tags: api, united-kingdom, county

[Wikishire](https://wikishire.co.uk/) have a helpful [lookup tool](https://wikishire.co.uk/lookup/) that allows you to find the traditional county for a given set of coordinates within the United Kingdom.  This is easily (and legally) scriptable.  Is anyone aware of a similar tool for modern administrative counties and unitary authorities?  Ideally districts too.

This feels like the sort of thing that might be possible with OpenStreetMap's [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), and OSM certainly has the required data, but I'm not sure how to query for relations containing a point, assuming it's possible at all.

Comment: download OS Boundary line and do it yourself is probably easiest

Comment: no, its a really simple solution would take about 10 minutes